# Dynamically add links into String in Wicket

Tags: java, hyperlink, wicket, dynamic

I have a string (user message) and I would like to find (using regexp) special codes in it and replace them with links. (For example, `@user` will be replaced with `<a href="wicket-url-to-user-profile">user</a>` thing.) How can it be done in the Wicket? I do not ask about regular expressions, it is Wicket-focused question.

Comment: Where would those links point? Within the application or to an external url?

Comment: Not sure what part you are asking about. The whole thing? Anyway, here is a good link for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234950/regex-for-beginners.

Comment: Regexp is easy part. I'm asking about Wicket-part.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need? And which part you're unsure about.

Comment: For example, @user will be replaced with <a href="wicket-url-to-user-profile">user</a> thing.

Comment: Is the 'string' being shown on an HTML page that's under the control of Wicket?

Comment: It is certainly possible but there's no built-in component for it as far as I know. I'll try to write up a couple of examples for you.

Comment: @artbristol String as a basic Java class containing user message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, Wicket has a very powerful feature for this.

Let's say this is your localization string with the key "some.resource.key":

```
This is a ${user}.
```

Then you add the following to your Wicket template:

```
<wicket:message key="some.resource.key">
    <a wicket:id="user">user</a>
</wicket:message>
```

In your Wicket page (or Panel), simply add your link as if you were adding it to the level where you put the wicket:message:

```
add(new Link("user"));
```

Now the link - you can use whatever implementation of link or any other component you like - is displayed correctly embedded in your localized string.

Comment: As I said, text is some user message. We do not know what this text is, and if it contains any codes. User does not know syntax `${user_nick}`, text can contain syntax errors. And, so you need to define `<a wicket:id="user">user</a>` for every user nick?

Comment: Than this in fact is not a (purely) Wicket-related question. Find the string to replace using a regexp, extract the username, find the user and replace the string with a link. Easy as that. To get the correct URL to a Wicket page, you can use any component's urlFor() method.

Answer (score 1):

Wicket has IResponseFilter. With this you can post-process the final HTML. I.e. you can search for ${anything} and replace it with 'whatever you want'.
To create nice looking URLs I suggest you to mount specific pages for the specific domain objects, e.g. Application#mountPage("/users/${user}", UsersPage.class), and create the urls with : RequestCycle.get().urlFor(UsersPage.class, pageParameters), where 'pageParameters' contains an entry with key 'user' and value 'whatever you extracted with RegEx'.